# question about limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

First off, thank you for viewing this question. I have two questions about limit.

1. I would appreciate if someone can check my proof. I somehow found this issue to be troublesome: prove $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}n^{1/p} = 1$ where $n>0, p\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

The proof is trivial if $\epsilon \geq 1$. So, I only consider the case $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

I need to find $N$ such that $\forall p>N \Rightarrow\rho(1,n^{1/p})<\epsilon$. (distance function is simply absolute value of the subtraction). I have set my N as $\lceil \frac{1}{log_n(1-\epsilon)}\rceil$. Is this a legitimate N?

2. In metric space $R^n_p$, how is $\lim_{n\rightarrow C}n$ defined? (C is a constant). Is this an expression that does not make sense in the given metric space? I can't obviously use the definition of limit since I can't properly apply distance function. If this is a wrong expression, hHow can I describe a scalar $n$ approaching a certain value $C$ in this metric space?

Thank you so much.

Comment: If $n>1$ then $\log_n(1-\epsilon)<0$, so your $N$ is $\leq0$. I think this is not what you want. I suggest thinking separately about the cases $n>1$ and $n<1$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll work on the separate case $n<1$.  Does my $N$ still hold for the case $n>1$?

Comment: It's the other way around; your $N$ works for $n<1$, but you need a different formula for $n>1$. Of course you would need to write out a proof that $\rho(1,n^{1/p})<\epsilon$, and if you are careful about signs in your inequalities you should see why your original formula only works for $n<1$.

Comment: I got it. $N = log_n(1+\epsilon)$. What about the second question? I am confused how to interpret a scalar approaching to a certain value in a certain Metric space. I can't obviously use the definition of limit defined in the metric space. Should I use definition defined in $R^2$ instead? $lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = q \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0: \rho(x,p) < \delta \Rightarrow \rho(f(x),q) < \epsilon$ // f(x) = x$ in this case.

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow c} a_n=k $ has a slightly different definition.  It is: for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta $ such that for all $d (n,c)<\delta $ we have $d (a_n,k)<\epsilon $.  I.e. as n tends to c, a_n tends to k.  So $\lim_{n\rightarrow c} n $ is what?  This is actually a *very* easy question.

Comment: What do you mean you can't apply the distance function?  Why not.  Of course you can.  $d ([x_1,x_2....x_n], [y_1,...y_n]) =\sqrt {\sum (x_i-y_i)^2} $.  But you want actually need it.  It means $\lim_{n \rightarrow C} n = k $ means $n=[n_1,.....n_n] $ and $k $ also in metric space.  For all e>0 there is a delta so that d (n,C) <  delta implies d (n,k) < e.  It should be clear k=C, as d (n,C) <e implies d (n,C) < e.

Comment: What I meant is, $C \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $n \neq (n_1, ..., n_n)$. It is not a vector; it is a scalar.